# How do I stream a subprocess's stderr while returning stdout as string?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'd like to capture standard output as a string when running a subprocess from  Python 3.9. At the same time, I would like standard error to stream to my console for debugging that lengthy subprocess.

`Popen.communicate()` has related functionality, but it seems that `subprocess`, as a high-level API, is preferable; and I am not sure how to treat the two streams separately.

This code returns the two of them as strings. How can I just stream stderr?

```
process = subprocess.run( ['sh', script], capture_output=True, text=True, env=env)
if process.returncode:
     raise Exception(f"Error {process.returncode} {process.stderr}")
return process.stdout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), you'll note that `capture_output` is not what you want:

> If capture_output is true, stdout and stderr will be captured.

If you want to capture *stdout* but not *stderr*, just set `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`. If I have a script named `script.sh` that contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "This is normal output"
echo "This is an error" >&2
```

I can capture the output like this:

```
>>> res = subprocess.run(['sh', 'script.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
This is an error
>>> res.stdout
b'This is normal output\n'
```

Output on *stderr* showed up on the console, while output to *stdout*
was captured in `res.stdout`.